# How would I change background color of alert view

Tags: ios, tvos

I am working on tvOS project, I need to create custom alert view with particular background color and text.

Comment: can you show some sample output which type do u need

Comment: Try to post what you've tried first. The public will not want to type the code for you. Show eventual troubles you are having and you are likely to get good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I have got the solution,

```
    if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? UIButton {
            next.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Focused)
            next.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 175/255, blue: 2/255, alpha: 1.0)
```